# Python as CGI in Node JS

Tags: jquery, python, node.js

I have a system that runs on python as my cgi back-end
so now im trying to implement a chat on my system , im using node js
but when i run it on node it , I always got this error

Is There a way to run my python file as cgi on node js?
or Should I stick to apache but how to load my node js server if I'd do that?

http://localhost:3000/cgi/main.py 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 couldn't be more generic. What do the logs say?

Comment: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.